# Binary How The Processor Distinguishes Between Two Same Byte Size Variable Types

Tags: c++, c, variables, types, binary

I'm trying to figure out how it is that two variable types that have the same byte size?

If i have a variable, that is one byte in size.. how is it that the computer is able to tell that it is a character instead of a Boolean type variable? Or even a character or half of a short integer?

Comment: It knows because you told it... `char c; // hey compiler, c is a char!`

Comment: ANSWERED!!!!
Thank you Seymour!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The processor doesn't know. The compiler does, and generates the appropriate instructions for the processor to execute to manipulate bytes in memory in the appropriate manner, but to the processor itself a byte of data is a byte of data and it could be anything.

The language gives meaning to these things, but it's an abstraction the processor isn't really aware of.

Comment: Alright but let's say that the .exe file goes onto a computer without the compiler, how does it tell the computer to treat it as a bool or int type then?

Comment: Because the compiled file uses specific instructions. If you want to add two integers together in the processor's instruction set, you load two integers from memory into registers and call the integer addition operation on those two registers, which will put its result into a third register. How does it know those are integers to load? Because they were loaded using a command which loads an integer from a particular address in memory. The compiler keeps track of which variables are where and what type they are so that it can generate these instructions correctly.

Comment: Interesting, but how is it that the compiler adds these instructions to the one byte allocated for a char. See, a byte only has 8 bits as we know and if all 8 bits are taken up to give the character the char type variable holds then where are these instructions dictating the type of variable it is held in?

Comment: What I mean is, if the entire byte is taken up by the value of the variable, where are these instruction stored? There are no more bits to store such instructions.. this is where I get confused.

Comment: @TorbenCarrington: The instructions are stored separately from the data that they act on. C code that increments a `char` would generate instructions that say "increment an 8-bit value at this address", and code that increments a `short` would generate instructions that say "increment a 16-bit value at that address". The compiler knows the type, and so knows which instructions it should generate.

Answer (score 3):

The computer is not able to do that. The compiler is. You use the char or bool keyword to declare a variable and the compiler produces code that makes the computer treat the memory occupied by that variable in a way that makes sense for that particular type.

A 32-bit integer for example, takes up 4 bytes in memory. To increment it, the CPU has an instruction that says "increment a 32-bit integer at this address". That's what the compiler produces and the CPU blindly executes it. It doesn't care if the address is correct or what binary data is located there.

The size of the instruction for incrementing the variable is another matter. It may very well be another 4 or so bytes, but instructions (code) are stored separately from data. There may be many instructions generated for a program that deal with the same location in memory. It is not possible to formally specify the size of the instructions beforehand because of optimizations that may change the number of instructions used for a given operation. The only way to tell is to compile your program and look at the generated assembly code (the instructions).

Also, take a look at unions in C. They let you use the same memory location for different data types. The compiler lets you do that and produces code for it but you have to know what you're doing.

Comment: Interesting, but how does it tell the computer to treat the memory occupied in a different way in a binary level? Everything has a different memory address and for something such as an integer type with 4 different memory addresses how does the compiler create a code telling the computer to treat all four of these memory addresses in a particular way?

Comment: @TorbenCarrington: The compiler doesn't need to. The CPU knows that an integer takes 4 consecutive bytes, so the compiler just needs to provide the address of the first byte. E.g. `mov eax, dword ptr[ebx]` (`dword`, Double Word is x86 speak for 32 bits).

Comment: Thank you :) Seymour answered my question too. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you *specify* the type. C++ is a strongly typed language. You can't write `$x = 10`. :)

It knows

```
 char c = 0;
```

is a `char` because of... well, the `char` keyword.

Comment: You can write `auto x = 10` though :)

Comment: I know that, but I was referring to the binary equivalent, not C++. What I mean is, how does binary [0/1] know that it is a character type instead of a Boolean type? Or a character instead of the second [or first] half of a short int, or even part of a double...?

Comment: @TorbenCarrington because the binary is generated by the compiler, that already has this info. It knows that at address `0x0ee234` it has a `bool`.

Comment: Also, please read my response to TomA. :) Thank you for helping thus far!

Comment: @TorbenCarrington it doesn't matter. The addresses are the same. It's too much to explain if you don't have any background in this area.

Comment: 01000001 and 65 are the same thing. how does it know whether it is ASCII char, or half of a short int?

Comment: @TorbenCarrington it resides at an address. The compiler, when it generates code, know what that address holds. :| Are you trolling?

Answer (score 0):

The computer only sees 1 and 0. You are in command of what the variable contains.

you can cast that data also into what ever you want.

```
char foo = 'a'; 
if ( (bool)(foo)  ) // true
{
    int sumA = (byte)(foo) + (byte)(foo);
    // sumA == (97 + 97)
}
```

Also look into [data casting](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) to look at the memory location as different data types. This can be as small as a char or entire structs.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it can't. Look at the restrictions of `dynamic_cast<>`, which tries to do exactly that. `dynamic_cast` can only work in the special case of objects derived from polymorphic base classes. That's because such objects (and only those) have extra data in them. Chars and ints do not have this information, so you can't use `dynamic_cast` on them.